# What happens to $dV$ and $dt$ in the proof of the logistic equation?

Tags: integration

I understand that the following antiderivative is correct.
\begin{align}
\int \left(\frac{1}{V}+\frac{1}{N-V}\right)\,dV&=\int r\,dt\\
\ln{\left|V\right|}+c_1-\ln{\left|N-V\right|}+c_2&=rt+c_3\\
\end{align}
However, can someone explain what happens to $dV$ and $dt$ when going from the first equation to the second? Why is the left-hand side not multiplied by $V$ but $r$ on the right-hand side is multiplied by $t$? Sorry, I'm a bit confused!

Comment: Yes, I know what that is...I'm just confused by the fact that dV and dt, in the rest of the proof, are treated as quantities. The logistic equation looks as follows:

\begin{equation}
\frac{dV}{dt}=rV\left(1-\frac{V}{N}\right)
\end{equation}

However, in this passage, they are treated as the usual "dx" that you find at the end of integrals to indicate the variable with respect to which we are integrating. Sorry, I should have probably asked my question more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

It is integration, not multiplication. Although, your weird rule of multiplying by the variable of integration does work for the integral $\int kdt=kt+C$.

Comment: Hi Korn, thank you for your answer! So you mean it's just a coincidence that it looks like r is being multiplied by t?

Comment: Exactly. You get it correctly.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Remember that $dV$ and $dt$ tell you what the integration variable is.

In the first case we are trying to find the antiderivative of $\frac{1}{V}+\frac{1}{N-V}$ with respect to $V$.  That, as you've said, is $$\ln|V| - \ln|N-V| + C$$ *because* when you differentiate with respect to $V$ you get back to $\frac{1}{V}+\frac{1}{N-V}$.  In the second case, notice that $r$ is a constant with respect to $t$, so when you find the antiderivative of $r$ with respect to $t$ you get $rt + C$.  This is because if you differentiate $rt + C$ with respect to $t$ you get back to $r$.

Comment: Thank you DMcMor, I think I'm getting there now. I still have an issue though. As you might have guessed, this manipulation comes from the proof of the logistic equation, which is described as follows:

\begin{equation}
\frac{dV}{dt}=rV\left(1-\frac{V}{N}\right)
\end{equation}

How can dV and dt, which initially seemed to be two actual quantities, become two references for the integration?

Comment: @MarcoCi, this is an example of a *separable differential equation*, if you're not sure what that means that would be the place to start.